# Low FPS on tensorRT YoloV3 Jetson Nano

Tags: nvidia-jetson, tensorrt

I converted my custom yolov3 model to onnx then onnx to tesnsorrt model on Jetson nano, it is taking 0.2 sec to predict on images i tried it on video and it is giving only 3 fps is there any way to increase this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FP16** inference mode instead of **FP32** and speed up your inference around 2x. Another option is using larger batch size which I’m not sure if it works on Jetson Nano since it has resource limitations.
You can find helpful scripts and discussion [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TensorRT/issues/585#issue-628102348)